# How to activate linking to JIRA issues

Tags: jira

I've seed in some JIRA projects that from the board or even the backlog, each issue created, you can click directly on it (link) to go to the actual issue.

In my case, when I see the board or backlog, I'm obligated to click on the issue then, in the appearing div on the right which shows the issue in more detail, you can see a link at the top to go to the issue, where can i configure this ?

As you can see, the **issue key** is not visible in each card, thus, no direct link to the issue. I first have to click on card, then in opening panel I see the issue key/link which I can then click. This is really annoying and time consuming.

The is the possibility to add 3 more fields to the cards; I tried in ***board settings >> card layout***  but no **issue key** is available.

[image]

### Edit

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: You want to go to the link directly, instead of showing up it in the right div?

Comment: @GowthamShivam yes, I want the name of the issue to be also a link to the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your links are there, it's just that they're shy and thus greyed-out:

[image]

You can Ctrl-click or middle-click the issue ID on the right, and the issue will open in a new tab.

Comment: jejeje yes, this is true but how do I place them on the left. I'll attach an image of what I'm expecting

Comment: Oh, that... Unfortunately, that's a design change that Atlassian rolled out a couple months ago. Just like they moved the Log Work to the top right menu etc. I also liked the old design more, but AFAIK there's no way to change it back. I'll have a look at it anyway!

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the rapid responses. If you find a way, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: The design change in question: https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/blog/2016/12/new-design-of-jira-software-issue-cards I can't read it all right now, maybe it says how to revert back to the old design.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you need to check and Configure is "Issue Details View" of the board. Take a look at https://confluence.atlassian.com/agile/jira-agile-user-s-guide/configuring-a-board/configuring-the-issue-detail-view